# MetalLB unable to reach external IP address

Tags: kubernetes, metallb, rancher-rke

I have a 3 nodes Rancher RKE custom cluster deployed on Rocky Linux VMs on vSphere.

I deployed MetalLB on the cluster and define IP pool from my node network.
When I create a LoadBalancer service everything looks fine and I'm getting external IP address from the pool, however I cannot reach this IP address from the node ip network, I can't even reach it from the nodes themselves, when I try to curl to the external IP address from one of the nodes I'm getting no where (No route to host).

Curl to the cluster IP or to the pod itself works fine.

Also if I create a NodePort service to the pod I can reach it with no issue from outside the cluster.
Any ideas?

Comment: The context of the question is unclear. Some configuration details, such as the IPs of the different components, and the configuration of MetalLB would be helpful for people to understand the context.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?